# Small view sliding from bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

I have a checklist app with a button to take notes. When I click that button, I want a small (not the entire size of the screen, let's say 1/3 of the height) view to be able to pop up from the bottom of the screen with an area to take notes. Pretty much exactly what the android keyboard does when you click a text field.

Now I'm not looking for answers on implementing the note-taking, etc, I'm just wondering if there are any libraries or best implementations for a feature like this? I looked up SlidingMenu library and SlidingUpPanel but I don't think either of them suit my case.

**Answered my own question below

Answer (score -1):

Turns out SlidingUpPanel does solve my problem as I can set a maximum height on the LinearLayout that slides from the bottom.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```